# An image in movement viewed by different cameras

Tags: optics

Why in the image the string looks like is in two places at the same time, what is the optical reason or is it because of how cameras work?

[image: String vibrating]

Comment: What does "in a modern camera the vibration pattern can be easily seen" mean?  Are you saying this picture was taken with a non-modern camera?

Comment: I believe your assessment of "a modern camera" is incorrect - the image is blurred because the aperture to the camera lens was left open for longer than the frequency of vibration. I'm not sure if it possible or not to avoid this, but that's why you see it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about properties of cameras. It might be appropriate on [photography.SE].

Comment: I see, I will edit it because the answer is a physical explanation

Answer (score 1):

When a camera takes a picture, the shutter is open for some small amount of time, during which the sensor takes in light.  If an object is moving, it is reflecting light towards the sensor from a range of locations during the time the shutter is open, so by the time the shutter closes, the image shows the object appearing to exist in a range of positions.

If the object is moving fast at a particular point in space, relatively little light is collected by the sensor from that location, and it will look dim.  If it is moving more slowly, more light will be collected from that point by the sensor, making it look brighter.

As the string vibrates back and forth, it is moving fastest in the middle of the vibrational movement, and slowest at the extreme ends of the movement, where it momentarily comes to rest.  That's why you can see a bright image of the string on either side, and a dim streaked image of the string in the middle.

Guitar strings typically vibrate in the 100-500 Hz range, depending on the note, so as long as the shutter speed is longer than 1/100 second, you would expect to see this kind of effect.